# Trying to edit the my.cnf file in mysql and it does not work

Tags: mysql, mode, cnf

I'm attempting to use cat /etc/my.cnf in mysql but when I do this, it just shows -> wanting me to keep putting in inputs.

However, when I put a semicolon at the end.

> cat /etc/my.cnf;

it throws an error.

How can I edit the /etc/my.cnf file?

I'm running this on terminal on a Mac and I got into the mysql server by using the command

> sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root

.

Comment: _It shows and error_ Would you like to share that error with us please

Comment: Cat is not for editing file, its just to view contents of file, to edit, use vi

Comment: mysql> cat /etc/my.cnf;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cat /etc/my.cnf' at line 1

Comment: And you cannot do anything like that from inside the `mysql>` shell

Comment: vi, vim, nano, all throws the same error

Comment: `where my.cnf` may also be useful

Comment: how can I edit the cnf file?

Comment: Have a care, if you have never used an editor before, you may do more damage than good

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you typing this in to the `mysql>` shell? If so, UNIX-shell commands like `cat` won't do anything useful. These aren't commands MySQL knows how to deal with.

You need to run these in a plain Terminal (shell) window *outside* of MySQL.

By default most systems launch the [`bash` shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) which has access to command-line tools like `vi`, etc. The MySQL shell is **SQL only**.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to edit MySQL configuration from MySQL shell but that will not work. Follow below 
 steps to edit the file

1. Open terminal and type below command to open mysql config file in textedit
2. sudo nano /etc/my.cnf
3. Save the file and restart MySQL

Hope this helps you